# How is character encoding inside Sakura done?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, charset

In the Sakura editor, you can have a `.txt` file with UTF-8 encoding, which contains 2 characters that are not available in EUC charset.

When I saved a `.txt` from UTF-8 to EUC in the editor, it all works well and all characters are displayed properly.

Does anybody know what logic the editor is using to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not following your question fully. What are your 2 characters which "are not available in EUC"? The source for this app is available here: http://sakura-editor.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sakura-editor/sakura/trunk/sakura_core/. I'm sure charcode.cpp/.h have what you're after. You can probably get the functionality you want from **libiconv** too.

Answer (score 0):

> which contains 2 characters which are not available in EUC charset

If you are seeing two characters `ÿþ` (hex `FF FE`) or `þÿ` (hex `FE FF`) *at the beginning of the first line*, then the file is encoded in UTF-16, not UTF-8. These characters are then actually the "[byte-order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order%5Fmark)" (BOM), which the editor should interpret, not show.

(Just in case you see *three* characters `ï»¿`, being hex `EF BB BF`, at the start of the first line, then that is the BOM for UTF-8. If you are seeing other characters, or not at the start of the first line, can you please edit your question to add some example?)